# How to create HLS stream from RGB data or jpeg image?

Tags: video-streaming

I have a situation where I have raw image data and I want to create HTTP live stream out of it.
Is there a way to do it? or is there any limitation to it?

Comment: Please show us what have you tried!

Comment: I am taking pixel data and using Real time streaming protocol to convert it in live streaming. But i want to do it using HTTP Live streaming.